# Class variable query in python

Tags: python, robotframework

**Framework:** Robot, **Language:** Python-3.7.1 **Proficiency:** Novice

I have a variable args=[] defined at class level. The values of the variables are being assigned from command prompt using module 'sys'

```
import sys

class Runner():
    args = []

    def argument_reader(self):
        self.args = list(sys.argv)

    def login(self):
        return self.args[1], self.args[2]
```

I could print all the values of args as long as execution stays within the module. If I wanted to call the same values from other module, it does not return anything as the values are being cleared out from the memory. Since class variables are static by default in python, why system is not RETAINING the values?

```
cmd line>>py Runner.py testing test@123
```

**For Example:**

```
Calling method from same class:-

run = Runner()
run.argument_reader()
print(run.login())

Output>>> testing, testing@123

Calling the same method from another class:-

runn = Runner.Runner()
print(runn.login())

output>> IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a singleton-type value, change your code to look like this.

```py
class Runner():
    args = []

    def argument_reader(self):
        Runner.args = list(sys.argv)

    def login(self):
        return Runner.args[1], Runner.args[2]
```

Otherwise, you'll have to call argument_reader() on each instance.

Comment: Further call on "argument_reader()" method would not have command line to pass data, correct?

Comment: OH. Yeah, if you want the class variable instead of the instance variable, use Runner.args, not run.args (probably).